# Distribute load evenly across many cycles

Tags: algorithms, scheduling

I am looking for a solution that is fast and still readable. I have to do this in C but the code will be static in the end, which mean I could use any tool to generate it.

I have a task which runs cyclically and calls different functions also cyclically

> Main functions cycle is 1.
>
> Function a has also cycle 1. So the main function calls it every time
>
> Function b has cycle 2. Main function calls it every second cycle.
>
> Function c has cycle 2.
>
> Function d has cycle 4.
>
> Function e has cycle 4.
>
> Function f has cycle 4.
>
> Function g has cycle 4.
>
> ... many more ....
>
> Function X has cycle 500.

If we have many functions that run in the same cycle we try to distribute them.
So for function b we would call it in one cycle and c in the other. Distributing the load evenly.
Similar for d to g. Each one gets called in a different cycle.

My current implementation is very bad.
Every developer who had to add their task to main function calculates their on modulo and calls when needed. This leads to a very unreadable code.

I was thinking of doing something like:

```
uint32 mod4 = timer % 4;
bool fourth_1 = mod4 == 0;
bool fourth_2 = mod4 == 1;
bool fourth_3 = mod4 == 2;
bool fourth_4 = mod4 == 3;
bool second_1 = fourth_1 || fourth_3;
bool second_2 = fourth_2 || fourth_4;
/* and so on*/
```

But this seems cumbersome and too error prone specially as the highest cycle time is too high.

How to approach this kind of problem?

-Edit-

As asked i have compiled some information about the number of functions that i have:

- 32 functions cycle 1
- 9 functions cycle 2
- 14 functions cycle 4
- 3 functions cycle 8
- 3 functions cycle 32
- 3 functions cycle 40
- 2 functions cycle 200
- 2 functions cycle 400

Comment: Do you have a cut-off point, above which there are so few infrequently running tasks that their distribution doesn't really affect the overall load any more?

Comment: @BartvanIngenSchenau I have added some more information.

Answer (score 2):

The starting point for solving this problem is a data structure. The elements of the structure are nodes (structs) containing:

- how to call one of the functions: a function pointer, any arguments, any other information
- when to call a function: the 'cycle' as you put it.

You can use a flat list created at compile time, but then the entire list will have to be searched at least once for each cycle, and that may not be good for performance. A better approach is to add each node to a data structure designed to minimise searching. I would suggest a list for each cycle modulo, so 8 lists for the data given.

- At initialisation time add each function node to the list(s) on which it should be called.
- On each cycle simply go down the list(s) that are applicable, calling each function in turn.

Simple, testable, maintainable, extensible.

Answer (score 1):

I may have your definition of "cycle" wrong. If "Cycle N" means that a method should be called when "timer" modulo N is 0, why not put pointers to those functions into a list or array of structure instances, and include in each structure, the "N" you want to modulo? Then after you increment "timer", check each structure to see if modulo N is 0. If so, invoke the function pointer.

After reading the problem description, I see that "Cycle N" has the additional restriction that only one function can run at once for a given N. To satisfy this requirement, keep an additional flag, "last run", in the structure mentioned above. Put each structure for a given N value in a separate list or array. This way you can mark the last run function, then unmark that one, run the next one, mark it, and so on, each time through.